# PHP data encryption and decryption

Tags: php

I am trying to encrypt data using php and insert into mysql. Encryption and insert actions working properly but decryption does not return actual string. Please see my code below for encryption

```
public function encryptText($text,$customer_id)
    {
        $key = $customer_id;
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        return $crypttext;
    }
```

For decryption

```
public function decryptText($ctext,$customer_id)
    {
            $key = $customer_id;
            $text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$ctext,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
            return $text;
    }
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: *"working properly but decryption does not return actual string"* -- Sooo, it's *not* working properly then? ;P

Comment: generally little point encrypting data in db, if the bad guys have access to the db they probably have access to the code used to encrypt the data.

Comment: could you post your "test" code, please? because your code works as it should. I suppose that there is some problem with string padding or $customer_id (key) parameter casting.

Comment: @Dagon: That's totally unfounded.

Comment: @Jon founded in much of what i have read.

Comment: @Dagon: I don't want to get into an argument, but it should be obvious that e.g. an SQL injection vulnerability can easily result in data disclosure without anyone getting access to any source code.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that you are not using the correct key to decrypt the encrypted data. Your code shows a number of issues *really* look into:

- The key should ideally be a binary string. What are the exact contents of `$customer_id`? Even if that is a string, it should be exactly either 128, 192, or 256 bits long. It doesn't look like it is.
- Even if the key were technically acceptable, using a customer id as a key does not really offer any security at all.
- The 256 in `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` does not specify the encryption strength but the *block size*. In almost all cases you should use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` instead -- in fact doing this is the same as AES. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not AES.

Comment: I have used customer_id (integer) as key.

Comment: @Vinay: That will not work. Please take some time to familiarize yourself with basic crypto literature, this mistake is so fundamental that I cannot give better advice than that. Even if it did work, your system would not be any more secure than before. Crypto is something that you have to do correctly, otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

These functions will take any PHP object and encrypt/decrypt them:

Encrypt JSON object Rijndael ECB base 64 encode

```
function ejor2eb($object, $key) {
    // Encode the object
    $object = json_encode($object, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    // Add length onto the encoded object so we can remove the excess padding added by AES
    $object = strlen($object) . ':' . $object;

    // Encrypt the string
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $result = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $object, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

    // Return the URL encoded string, with the encryption type attached
    return 'jor2eu:' . base64_encode($result);
}
```

Decrypt JSON object Rijndael ECB base 64 decode

```
function djor2eb($string, $key, $default = false) {
    // Remove the encryption type, and decode the string
    $binary = base64_decode(substr($string, 7));
    if (!$binary) {
        return $default;
    }

    // Decrypt the string
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $result = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $binary, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

    // Remove encrption padding
    $tokens = null;
    preg_match('/^([0-9]+):/i', $result, $tokens);
    if (sizeof($tokens) !== 2) {
        return $default;
    }
    $result = substr($result, strlen($tokens[1]) + 1, $tokens[1]);

    // Decode the ecoded object
    $object = json_decode($result);

    return $object;
}
```